# Как изменить кодировку отчета об ошибке в PHP?

Tags: php, кодировка, warning

При выполнении скрипта запроса

```
<?php
mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
?>
```

при выключенном сервере MySQL, получаю в браузере отчет об ошибке (warning):

> mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): ��������� �� �����������, �.�. ������
>   ������� ������ ������ �� ���������.

Битый текст - это строка, которая является сообщением: "Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение." Использую локальный веб-сервер сборки XAMPP v.3.2.

Как получить эту строку корректно в отчете об ошибке?

Comment: сервер ответ то в utf отдает?

Comment: @teran Да, нечитаемые символы это тоже кодировка utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло изменить кодировку в с "UTF-8" на "windows-1251" в php.ini

```
;default_charset = "UTF-8"
default_charset = "windows-1251"
```

Answer (score 0):

Вывод ошибки MySQL будет зависеть от самой сборки, LANG на сервере (+еще некоторое количество всякой фигни) и того, как отображает у тебя text WEB-сервер

Я бы посоветовал начать отладку с установки в `.htaccess` параметра

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

В 90% случаев на этом все и заканчивается

Если не поможет, иди по шагам:

1. На какой ОС все это работает и какая кодировка в этой ОС по умолчанию
2. В какой кодировке живет сервер SQL
3. В какой кодировке живет WEB-сервер

Кстати говоря, полученный текст можешь взять, скопировать в буфер и вставить вот сюда: https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/ - классная штука, позволяет быстро и просто понять, что происходит

Только копируй прям сразу где увидел, а не из поста выше, например. Символ `�` - вполне себе печатный символ UTF-8, кодировать его куда-то еще не получится ) Так случается после вставки кракозябр куда-то, где контент в UTF-8.. они просто преобразуются в обычные UTF-8 символы.

UPD. Я провел эксперимент:

1. Взял вашу исходную предполагаемую строчку `mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.`
2. Записал ее в файл в кодировке UTF-8:

   $ env | grep LANG
   LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8

   $ echo "mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение." > q686819.txt
3. Полученный файл перегнал из UTF-8 в CP-1251 (она же windows-1251)

   $ iconv -f utf-8 -t windows-1251 ./q686819.txt

   mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): ����������� �� �����������, �.�. �������� ��������� ������ ������ �� �����������.

Консоль у меня отображает вывод в UTF-8, но выводимые символы имеют кодировку CP-1251

Отсюда можно сделать следующий полезный для вас вывод: исходный текст ваша сборка MySQL выводит в кодировке windows-1251 (скорее всего потому что собрана под Windows, а там в русской локализации по умолчанию именно windows-1251). А вопросики вы видите потому, что смотрите на символы через призму кодировку utf-8

Решение: либо поменять сборку MySQL на EN, без локализации на русском (возможно там в параметрах можно поменять LANG для ошибок или что-то вроде того - обычно такие пакеты делают мультиязычными, а язык выбирается из параметров ОС), либо ничего не менять и выводить в windows-1251 (как сейчас), но смотреть на это через призму той же кодировки windows-1251, например в `.htaccess`

```
AddDefaultCharset windows-1251
```

Попробуйте, тут нужны эксперименты именно с вашей сборкой и на Windows. К сожалению подробнее я вам не подскажу - пользуюсь Linux и обычными Apache httpd и mariadb из репозиториев. Но направление определенно верное

Comment: ОС - Windows 8. В php.ini default_charset = "UTF-8". В my.ini character_set_server=utf8. Смена кодировки веб-сервера, по моим наблюдениям, не решает проблему.

Comment: Обновил ответ, смотрите

Comment: Если из командной строки (cmd.exe) пытаюсь подключиться к выключенному серверу MySQL, то система выдает: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061 "Unknown error"). Как видно, отчет об ошибке отличается от того, что выдает веб-сервер на котором запущен скрипт PHP. Возможно, что сборка заимствует у ОС эту строку, которая в кодировке windows-1251, и не может ее преобразовывать в utf-8. Возникает вопрос, где и на каком этапе? Сообщения об этой проблеме встречал на других форумах. Там так же высказывается это предположение.

Comment: А не проще ли вам самому перехватывать результат подключения `mysqli_connect()` и разбирать ошибку через результат функции http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php. Подавить вывод ошибки на экран можно собакой перед вызовом: `$link = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');`, и если `$link` плохой, то выводите ошибку самостоятельно. Смотрите Пример #1 по ссылке. Там и с кодировкой можно порешать, если строка будет в вопросиках опять.

Comment: Конечно, перехватывал и получал ту же битую строку.

Comment: Удалось понять, откуда появляется сама строка. Если подключаться через командную строку к выключенному MySQL серверу, то получаю ответ `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061 "Unknown error")`. И вот при просмотре `perror 10061`, получаю эту самую фразу, которая выводится в кодировке cp1251. Т.к. кодировка окна командной строки cp866, то в нем фраза тоже нечитабельна. А при просмотре ее в cp65001, получаем все символы в виде �.